# What happens when we travel to our new dimension?

Tags: science-based, space, physics

My advanced human society understands how to search & find data on other dimensions; as well, we can travel if they're compatible.

For years all we've found was data indicating dimensions with totally different laws of physics and chaos, many without space as we know it.  Finally, we've found a dimension that shares our laws of physics (bear with me, this is for a young adult short story), and is composed entirely of just expanded "space," no matter.

While it would be prepared for gravity, there are no gravitational waves.  While it would be prepared to accept the presence of electro-magnetism, light, etc., it doesn't exist.

We are traveling there to explore it, in a ship similar to a sleek space shuttle.

**What are the ramifications when we arrive, presenting this empty universe with matter, gravity (our mass), light (from inside)?  And what, if any, additional protections would our shuttle need?**

I am putting this as science-based *only for the part where a space shuttle arrives in a universe like ours, but with nothing in it*.  I realize the initial scenario of a mass-less universe is not science-based.

Comment: Well, if I were you I wouldn't even waste the excursion. The dimension will be devoid of anything but light, and possible even that. Photons are massless, by the way. So you just are in a giant blank expanse of light and nothingness.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds to me like the universe you're visiting has already suffered its heat death: all the stars have burned out, and all the atoms have simply reached a state of equilibrium.

This universe will be utterly empty, and dead. There is nothing to explore, as there is nothing to see.

However, by the sheer fact of you travelling there you are now causing new interactions between particles. It could be that by releasing new energy into this system you could kick-start it back into being (most likely this would require a lot of energy, however - the Big Bang - and you would only make a minor stir).

Another concern is the fact that you are "removing" energy from your own universe into another. I'm pretty sure that breaks physics.

Comment: If the OP is looking for a post-heat death scenario, then [this question](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/37885/a-brief-dip-into-the-heat-death-of-the-universe) may have some relevant information

Comment: It would be beyond the heat death, all of the particles would have already decayed into photons or something. In any case, there are no atoms to interact with. So this doesn't really answer the question within the bounds set by the OP.

Answer (score 2):

Practically speaking, it would be basically the same as traveling through space, only safer.  Space is pretty close to vacuum as it is, and the stuff in it (micrometeors, cosmic radiation) are the hazards of space flight - our spacecraft have to be designed to resist them.  In an empty universe, you could do away with most of the protective layering and radiation shields - all you would need to worry about would be keeping the air in.

The main issue you would have to deal with would be retaining energy - without stars, there is no means of recharging energy once it is lost.  Any excursions to the new universe would have to be temporary.

The presence of your spacecraft would not "trigger" anything, as there is nothing there to be "triggered".  You would be an unusual presence in an empty universe, but no more than that.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the way you enter that space. The way the laws of physics allows it (actually it doesn't, because There's no way you can collect enough energy to escape from our universe) let's imagine you could somehow... Your entry will be flashier than a Rock star. Igniting the topology and the thermodynamics of that poor old lonely Euclidean space, it will start binging and banging...
In "http://www.theguardian.com/education/2005/feb/22/highereducation.highereducationprofile" we read
...Kaku slips into overdrive as he explains all the implications. "String theory predicts the universe is like a soap bubble that is expanding and dying," he says. Billions of years from now stars will blink out; the night sky will be dark and the oceans will freeze over. But we may have an escape route. Our soap bubble co-exists with other soap bubbles; every time a black hole forms it may be creating a baby universe. The matter being sucked in may be blown out the other side, creating a white hole in a twin universe, which will expand very rapidly, like our own Big Bang...

Comment: This sounds much more like a comment than a real answer. I know you cannot yet comment on answers, but you will soon enough. Meanwhile, you should make sure you really answer the questions.

Comment: You mean elaboration?

Comment: I think that could be a good answer, but as it stands... it isn't. So yes, if you could elaborate, especially on your last sentence.